# Executar função PHP dentro de onclick ou href

Tags: php, html

Estou com um sistema de logoff, e ele funciona, mas, eu não queria executar ele pelo uso de URL:

```
$logoff = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'logoff', FILTER_VALIDATE_BOOLEAN);
if($logoff){
    unset($_SESSION['userlogin']);
    session_destroy();
    header('Location: ../painel');
}
```

---

```
<a href="painel.php?logoff=true">Sair</a>
```

Teria alguma forma de, colocar um `onclick` por exemplo, dentro desse `<a>` pra executar uma função em PHP? Igual fazemos com javascript, por exemplo:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)">Sair</a>
```

Ou vocês acham que eu poderia continuar fazendo o logoff desse jeito?

Eu queria por exemplo fazer:

```
<a href="<?php echo minhaFuncao()?>">Sair</a>
```

Comment: Se pretende executar PHP por trás e obter algum resultado, está na verdade à procura de Ajax

Answer (score 0):

Fazendo uso de javascript, o legal é que dentro da função, você passa qualquer arquivo para redirecionar, inclusive com parâmetros:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="redireciona('logoff.php');">Logoff</a>

<script>
    function redireciona(pagina) {
        var pagina;
        parent.location.href = pagina;
      return false;
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Não sei se entendi muito bem sua questão.

Mas uma coisa que você pode fazer é chamar uma função JS e dentro dela ter uma função PHP. Desse modo você pode ter a função PHP que quiser sendo chamada por um comando JS.